# Conjugate dīrígere as 1st-person past tense

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, english, perfect-tense

How might I say dīrígere — which is conjugated dirigo, I think, in first person present tense, to first person past tense? Perfect, imperfect, I’d like to know them both.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This kind of an answer is found in conjugation tables that come with many books and websites. What material are you using to learn Latin? Are you struggling to interpret a table?

Answer (score 2):

**Dīrigō** is a third conjugation verb.

The imperfect forms regularly, **dīrigēbam**, as you can find in any [3rd conjugation table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_conjugation#Third_conjugation).

The perfect is a bit more tricky. Since third conjugation verbs have different roots for perfect, the best option if you don't know it by heart, is to look at a [dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Ddirigo1), where you'll see that the standard form for the perfect (i.e., the 1st pers. sing.) in this case is **dīrēxī**.

Verbs in Latin dictionaries usually display three (or five) forms to help conjugate a verb using tables. E.g. **dīrigō, [dī]-rēxī, [dī]-rēctum** (1st pers. sing. present; 1st pers. sing. perfect; supine) or **dīrigō, [dīrig]-is, [dīrig]-ere, [dī]-rēxī, [dī]-rēctum** (1st&2nd pers. sing. present; infinitive; 1st pers. sing. perfect; supine)